# Mysql - If condition is true, then only count certain cases

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
select itinerary.id as "itin_id", itinerary.`name`,
count((CASE WHEN(year(starts_on) = 2017) and (sign_up_date <= "2017-11-02") THEN 1 END)) AS `2017_sign_ups`

FROM `departure`
JOIN `itinerary` on `itinerary`.`id` = `departure`.`itinerary_id`
Join reservation on departure.id = reservation.departure_id

WHERE itinerary.trip_type not in ("V")
and reservation.`status` = "A"
and itinerary.season >= 2017

group by itinerary.id
```

I essentially need to figure out how to include this logic:
If a record has a status of cancelled, then count cases where cancellation_date <= some_date, while also counting all records with an active status.

Sorry if this is something super obvious, still finding my Mysql legs.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @kirch, I guess you should to learn about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: invalid ANSI SQL query.. `select itinerary.id as "itin_id", itinerary.`name`,
count((CASE WHEN(year(starts_on) = 2017) and (sign_up_date,.... group by itinerary.id` is prone to invalid results.  https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: do you want to count `cancellation_date <= some_date` regardless of active status?

Comment: Hi @danihp, thank you, I suppose you provided that guide because I included my entire query? I'll make sure to be more minimal in the future.

Comment: @kirch, from scratch man, from scratch.

Comment: @kirch You `GROUP BY` should include all non-aggregated columns.  Your query won't even run in other dbms, except for maybe `MySQL`.

Comment: @kirch What is 'V'?  What is 'A'?  Help us help you.  Give some explanation that make us understand.